# Android Experts - Need your help to display Images quickly in low internet areas and low quality phones

Tags: java, android, image

We are developing a private social media App for colleges in Android. However, my current Android App rendering speed for images are very slow. It takes approx. 5 seconds for images to appear and in this day and age its criminal.

We have tried different options and our current android developer is not able to solve this. Can anyone suggest alternate options?
Here is what we have done so far.

Few Questions Upfront:
    1. Where are we messing up in the process? Please advise
    2. Is the sizing of thumbnails correct?
    3. Any suggestions for libraries in Java to compress images (lossless) before sending to backend server

Here are the steps that we followed

```
1. Compress the image from device before sending to server via API - We are doing this for jpeg only. Need to do this for .PNG 
AFAIK, this is the code used. As I am not an Android developer, I am not sure this is complete.  

*Bitmap scaledBitmap = ImageCompression.compressImage(1328.0f, 1771.0f, sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        if (null != scaledBitmap)
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        return destFile;
public static File getCompressedImage(File srcFile, File destFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = ImageCompression.compressImage(1328.0f, 1771.0f, srcFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        if (null != scaledBitmap)
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        return destFile;
    }

######### Used this code to do compression - https://gist.github.com/walteranyika/2db99439225a82d2c1497e6ab61a8a3d  #################### ImageCompression.Java ######## Relevant parts are pasted here.
*Canvascanvas=null;
if(scaledBitmap!=null){
canvas=newCanvas(scaledBitmap);
canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,middleX-bmp.getWidth()/2,middleY-bmp.getHeight()/2,newPaint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
}**


2. Server is creating thumbnails using thumbnilator 
    a. We are creating 4 sized thumbnails for 4 phone sizes with size less than 100 KB by reducing quality
        i. All Portrait images and all width * height and in DP
        ii. Small - 150 * 150
        iii. Medium - 200 * 200 
        iv. Large - 210 * 420 
        v. X-Large - 500 * 640
3. Enabled BucketAccelerateConfiguration in AWS
4. Thumbnails along with original image is sent to target device from server via API
5. Using a combination of Glide and Picasso libraries to display thumbnails and original image in the backend
    a. If thumbnails are empty, we are displaying original URL
    b. If the thumbnails are available, we are displaying Thumbnail till original image is displayed


*if(TextUtils.isEmpty(thumbUrl)){
    GlideApp.with(getContext())
    .load(imageUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
    .dontAnimate()
    .dontTransform()
    .into(imageView);
}else{
Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
    .load(thumbUrl)//thumbnailurlgoeshere
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
    .resize(AppConstants.IMAGE_SIZE,AppConstants.IMAGE_HEIGHT)
    .transform(HomeActivity.blurTransformation)
    .into(imageView,newCallback(){
    @Override
publicvoidonSuccess(){
    Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext())
    .load(imageUrl)//imageurlgoeshere
    .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
    .into(imageView);
    }
@Override
publicvoidonError(){
    GlideApp.with(getContext())
    .load(imageUrl)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
    .dontAnimate()
    .dontTransform()
    .into(imageView);
    }
    });
}
}*
```

Comment: _"private social media App for colleges"_ -- wasn't that called "The Face Book" a dozen years or so ago?

Comment: We are much different - I can answer you separately. In the meanwhile, Can you answer the question that I asked and don't deviate from the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Androids ThumbnailUtils and generate as per your requirement thumbnail of the selected image and than convert it to bitmap and set.

It works faster.

You can get all the information about ThumbnailUtils here,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html